# ggplot2 grouped bar chart for months over several years is producing overlapping bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart and the bars are crowded and overlapping for my x-values. How do I get the grouped bar chart to plot correctly?

I've tried formatting the date with `as.yearmon` to sort the table for graphing; I have also formatted the table with year and month in separate columns for ease of graphing. However, neither format has worked for me. I have tried `as.date` and `lubridate` also and have had no luck so far.

Here is what my data frame looks like:

```
structure(list(Month = c("August", "July", "June", "May", "November", 
"October", "September", "April", "August", "December", "February", 
"July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October", "September", 
"April", "August", "December", "February", "January", "July", 
"June", "March", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", 
"November", "October", "September", "January", "August", "July", 
"June", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", "August", 
"December", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October", 
"September", "April", "August", "December", "February", "January", 
"July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October", "September", 
"April", "August", "February", "January", "July", "June", "March", 
"May", "November", "October", "September", "January", "August", 
"July", "June", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "December", "February", "July", "June", "March", "May", 
"November", "October", "September", "April", "August", "December", 
"February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", 
"October", "September", "April", "August", "February", "January", 
"July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October", "September", 
"January"), Year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2020L), DSG.Station = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("9M", "14M", "37M"
), class = "factor"), Richness = c(3.75, 3, 11.5, 6.16666666666667, 
0, 0, 1.5, 4.25, 5.75, 3.5, 0, 8, 9.5, 2.6, 7.75, 5.25, 9.16666666666667, 
6.25, 6.5, 10, 7, 4, 3.5, 8, 11, 5.75, 7, 7.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
8.33333333333333, 7, 6, 4.5, 3.5, 10, 5.5, 8.5, 10.5, 2, 5.5, 
12.5, 5, 5, 5.5, 6, 5.66666666666667, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 4.5, 9, 5.16666666666667, 
5.66666666666667, 7, 0.5, 8, 7.25, 6.5, 5, 6.5, 6, 5, 4.75, 3.25, 
7.5, 10, 6.5, 8.25, 7, 8, 6.66666666666667, 11, 10.5, 9.5, 5, 
7.5, 6.5, 4.5, 10, 4.5, 3.5, 8.5, 3, 4, 4.5, 9, 10, 1.8, 3.25, 
1, 5.5, 6, 3.5, 1, 7, 5, 2.5, 6.66666666666667, 3.75, 5.5, 6.5, 
7, 9.5, 4, 6.25, 3.5, 8.5, 11.3333333333333, 6.75, 6.5, 5, 8.66666666666667, 
7.33333333333333, 9, 9, 4.5, 3, 9, 13.5, 6.5, 9, 3.5, 3, 11, 
6.5), yrmn = c("2016 August", "2016 July", "2016 June", "2016 May", 
"2016 November", "2016 October", "2016 September", "2017 April", 
"2017 August", "2017 December", "2017 February", "2017 July", 
"2017 June", "2017 March", "2017 May", "2017 November", "2017 October", 
"2017 September", "2018 April", "2018 August", "2018 December", 
"2018 February", "2018 January", "2018 July", "2018 June", "2018 March", 
"2018 May", "2018 November", "2018 October", "2018 September", 
"2019 April", "2019 August", "2019 February", "2019 January", 
"2019 July", "2019 June", "2019 March", "2019 May", "2019 November", 
"2019 October", "2019 September", "2020 January", "2016 August", 
"2016 July", "2016 June", "2016 May", "2016 November", "2016 October", 
"2016 September", "2017 April", "2017 August", "2017 December", 
"2017 July", "2017 June", "2017 March", "2017 May", "2017 November", 
"2017 October", "2017 September", "2018 April", "2018 August", 
"2018 December", "2018 February", "2018 January", "2018 July", 
"2018 June", "2018 March", "2018 May", "2018 November", "2018 October", 
"2018 September", "2019 April", "2019 August", "2019 February", 
"2019 January", "2019 July", "2019 June", "2019 March", "2019 May", 
"2019 November", "2019 October", "2019 September", "2020 January", 
"2016 August", "2016 July", "2016 June", "2016 May", "2016 November", 
"2016 October", "2016 September", "2017 April", "2017 August", 
"2017 December", "2017 February", "2017 July", "2017 June", "2017 March", 
"2017 May", "2017 November", "2017 October", "2017 September", 
"2018 April", "2018 August", "2018 December", "2018 February", 
"2018 January", "2018 July", "2018 June", "2018 March", "2018 May", 
"2018 November", "2018 October", "2018 September", "2019 April", 
"2019 August", "2019 February", "2019 January", "2019 July", 
"2019 June", "2019 March", "2019 May", "2019 November", "2019 October", 
"2019 September", "2020 January")), row.names = c(NA, -125L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code for the plot:

```
ggplot(rich.mean2, aes(factor(DSG.Station), fill=DSG.Station, y=Richness, x=yrmn)) + 
  geom_bar (position = position_dodge(2.5), width= 2, colour= 'black', stat='identity')+
  ggtitle('Richness Per Month')+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=7, colour =  'black'), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black" ))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=rich.mean2$yrmn)
```

You can see how the plot is very overlapping. The error I am getting is:

```
Warning message: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot the data in the correct order, we can transform the months into a factor using `month.name` (built into base R). Then, we can `arrange` by `Year` and `Month`, and combine them into one column, `yrmn`. Now that they are in order, we can set the order with `factor`. Now, we can plot as normal, but can set the spacing between groups to `width = 0.7` and increase spacing between bars with `position_dodge`, where we can specify the distance between bars. Note: You cannot increase the normal `width` parameter too much when using  `position_dodge` as it will push the bars into the other x-intervals, which is the reason for the warning message (i.e., `position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals`).

```
library(tidyverse)

rich.mean2 %>% 
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.name)) %>% 
  arrange(Year, Month) %>% 
  unite(yrmn, c(Month:Year), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(yrmn = factor(yrmn, levels = unique(yrmn))) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = yrmn, y = Richness, fill = DSG.Station)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.7,
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 1
  )) +
  ggtitle('Richness Per Month') +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 7, colour =  'black'),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 90,
      vjust = 0.5,
      hjust = 1
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

*Output*

[image]

**Update 1**

For filling in missing months, we can use base R `month.name` within `complete` from `tidyr`. Next, I convert the month name to a number and add the leading 0, which is needed for the `date` format. Next, I combine `Year`, `Month`, and day (i.e., "01"). Then, I arrange by `yrmn`. Then, I convert to just show month-year. Then, if you want to go back to names rather than month numbers, then we can convert it back. However, if you are fine with date numbers (i.e., 09-2016), then you can comment out the line with `separate` and the 2 subsequent lines (i.e., through `unite`). So, now you will see, gaps where there is no data for a given month.

```
df %>% 
  complete(Month = month.name, nesting(Year), fill = list(Richness = NA, DSG.Station = NA)) %>% 
  mutate(Month = formatC(match(Month, month.name), width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")) %>% 
  mutate(yrmn = paste(Year, Month, "01", sep="-")) %>% 
  arrange(yrmn) %>% 
  mutate(yrmn = format(as.Date(yrmn, format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%m-%Y")) %>% 
  separate(yrmn, c("Month", "Year"), sep = "-") %>% 
  mutate(Month = with(., month.abb[as.integer(str_remove(Month, "^0+"))])) %>% 
  unite("yrmn", c(Month, Year), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(yrmn = factor(yrmn, levels = unique(yrmn))) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = yrmn, y = Richness, fill = DSG.Station)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.7,
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 1
  )) +
  ggtitle('Richness Per Month') +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 7, colour =  'black'),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 90,
      vjust = 0.5,
      hjust = 1
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

*Output*

[image]

**Update 2**

If you want to remove the first NAs until you reach a value, then we can use a combination of `complete.cases` and `cumsum`, then we can also do the same thing in reverse for the end of the dataframe.

```
df %>%
  complete(Month = month.name, nesting(Year), fill = list(Richness = NA, DSG.Station = NA)) %>%
  mutate(Month = formatC(match(Month, month.name), width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0"),
         yrmn = paste(Year, Month, "01", sep="-")) %>%
  arrange(yrmn) %>%
  mutate(yrmn = format(as.Date(yrmn, format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%m-%Y")) %>%
  separate(yrmn, c("Month", "Year"), sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(Month = with(., month.abb[as.integer(str_remove(Month, "^0+"))])) %>%
  unite("yrmn", c(Month, Year), sep = " ") %>%
  filter(cumsum(complete.cases(.)) != 0 & rev(cumsum(rev(complete.cases(.)))) != 0) %>%
  mutate(yrmn = factor(yrmn, levels = unique(yrmn))) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = yrmn, y = Richness, fill = DSG.Station)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           width = 0.7,
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 1
  )) +
  ggtitle('Richness Per Month') +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 7, colour =  'black'),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 90,
      vjust = 0.5,
      hjust = 1
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

*Output*

[image]

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. I edited the original post to show the data I'm working with, the code altered with position_dodge as suggested, and the graph that it is producing. I thought that posting a simplified version of the data frame would be sufficient but maybe the issue itself is connected to my data frame. I'm thinking that maybe the sorting of dates in the data frame is making it plot weird if depending on what order ggplot2 chooses x-values to plot. But I really have no clue

Comment: @fishyfishy Can you edit your question and provide your data via `dput`? You can input `df(rich.mean2` into the console, then you can paste the results into your question. That is more helpful than just providing in table form (and more reproducible). Can you also post an image of what the error is?

Comment: I will do that. I apoligize, I'm new to stack overflow and R and I appreciate the guidance

Comment: I updated the original post. Let me know if any other info would be helpful

Comment: @fishyfishy I have updated my answer now. Let me know if that was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for. In this data set I have periods where no data was collected. For example, Dec 2016- Jan 2017. I would still like to show these dates on the graph but with no columns to have a consistent x-axis. Is there another way to do this besides manually inputing each date into the data frame?

Comment: thank you, I marked the answer as the accepted answer

Comment: if I wanted to leave out the months on either side of the data (2016 and 2020 months that have no data) but keep all of the other months in the plot, then how could that be done?

Comment: @fishyfishy I've add an additional `filter` line into the code (i.e., **Update 2**), which only removes the NAs at the beginning and end, but leaves the others that are in between months with values intact.

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to add a secondary y-axis displaying a separate data set as a line plot to overlay the existing bar plot would you know how that is possible with ggplot? I have searched and tried variations of sec.axis but I am having difficulty producing the line to overlay the existing bar plot

Comment: The main issue that I am having is trying to plot a secondary y-axis that has a different number of values than the other data set. I'm not sure if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: @fishyfishy It's sometimes a little tricky to add secondary axes (though very possible), and Hadley is generally not a fan of them unless in very simple cases. Sometimes it's better to facet. But regardless, I would post a new question with what exactly you are looking for with the secondary axes with sample data, expected output, etc. You can always provide a link to this question too if they are related.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a question regarding the secondary axis but with slightly different data. It is under the title "ggplot2 secondary axis with different amount of data points than other data plotted on chart in R"